# How to get this type of effect using javascript html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I am trying to make this type of effect using javascript, need some help how to implement it.

View Images from here:-
https://ibb.co/2c9y9jV
https://ibb.co/Jpqk3xr

My code:

```js
function move(e) {
  console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY);
  let x = e.clientX - 520;
  let y = e.clientY - 210;
  let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('after')[0];
  ele.style.transform = "translate3d(" + x + "px," + y + "px,0px)"
}
var temp = false;

function toggle() {
  temp = !temp;
  if (temp) {
    let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('after')[0];
    ele.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('after')[0];
    ele.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  z-index: 100;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  background: white
}

.image-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<div class="image-container">
  <img onmousemove="move(event)" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
  <div class="after">
  </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't be able to make effect like image

Comment: do you want the bulr effect ?

Comment: No basically when I click toggle button a black colored box will appear which will cover the whole image so when I take my cursor at where ever part of that black box I want to reveal my image that part (which is hiding behind box)